# iOS: Adding googlemail account button does not respond

Tags: settings, ios

So I have two google accounts already set up on my phone. These were set up prior to iOS 12 update. Now when I try to add a new Googlemail account, nothing happened a when I tap on the button in “settings > passwords and accounts > add account”.

Any ideas what might be going on? It can’t be a security thing because I don’t even to the screen which asks for credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as that - button doesn’t work.

I added my gmail account via Exchange instead. Works fine!

https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/www.imore.com/how-set-exchange-accounts-your-iphone-ipad-or-ipod-touch%3famp

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. And, just providing a link isn't very helpful as it may no longer work in future. Instead, could you please edit your answer (there's an _edit_ link below it) to include a summary of the content you're linking to? This will make your answer more self-contained and help preserve it for other users in future.

Comment: This worked, but not an ideal solution. Wonder why iOS can’t react to the button?